# Breathable Membrane Tyvek

Tags: ventilation, shed, timber-framing

Log Cabin - Would i have  moisture issues if i attach a breathable membrane to the outside studded wall leaving a 20mm gap for moisture then attach treated 44mm tongue and groove on the outside. I intend to fill the studded wall with rockwool then a plastic vapor membrane then plasterboard internally.